IE11 Compatibility Mode bypass for sub domain
I am using a group policy to support some legacy web sites by reverting the Edge browser to IE11. The process basically tells the browser to look up an XML file that lists the sites that need to open in IE11.
To be clear this is working perfectly for years now, except that now the sub-domain needs to open in Edge.
I am faced with an issue where a sub-domain should still open in Edge, but I have not been able to come up with any way to prevent the redirect in the xml code.
Here is the sites.xml file
<site-list version="205">
<!-- File creation header -->
<created-by>
    <tool>EnterpriseSitelistManager</tool>
    <version>10240</version>
    <date-created>20150728.135021</date-created>
</created-by>
<!-- Begin Site List --> 
<site url="sub.skip_redirect_site.com">
    <compat-mode>default</compat-mode>
    <open-in>None</open-in>
</site>
<site url="www.redirect_site.com">
<compat-mode>IE7Enterprise</compat-mode>
    <open-in>IE11</open-in>
</site>
<site url="example.com">
    <compat-mode>default</compat-mode>
    <open-in>IE11</open-in>
</site> 

I have even tried a style file with an if condition to pass over if there was a tag flag not to redirect but would rather find a way to get the above xml to not redirect to IE11.
I have tried a few options for this line as well....
<open-in>None</open-in>

like
<open-in>Edge</open-in>

But nothing seems to work.
